# JQuery nested ajax post with json firing only once

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, post, nested

I'm trying to write some JS using JQuery to get a list of servers and then request data about each one, each time using a post and returning some JSON. Effectively a nested POST.

1. AJAX POST returns JSON containing list of servers
2. Iterate through list of servers and perform an AJAX POST that will return some data about each server

Problem: The second AJAX POST is only occurring once, for the last server - however (if there are 5 servers returned within the first post, for example) the alert(compName) is happening 5 times and the doSomething function is only being called once. In the network trace the POST is being made 5 times.

I've tried the following to fix it:

- Make the POSTs synchronous
- Use JQuery promise()
- Change the callback function from the POST
- Change the $.each to differing iteration functions

Anyway, here is the code, getServerList() is called first:

```
var server = 'localhost';

function getServerList() {

  //get data back from web page listing server options
  $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "http://"+server+"/GetJSONData.aspx",
      data: { listservers: "true" },
      dataType: "json"
    }).done(function( data ) {

      $.each(data, function() {
         loadServer(data['serverName']);
      });
  });
};

function loadServer(serverName)
{
    var URL = "http://"+server+"/GetJSONData.aspx";
    var data = new Object();
    data.server = serverName;
    alert(compName);
    $.post(URL, data, function(resp) { 
        doSomething(resp);
    }, 'json');
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: `$.each(data` iterates on data so this element must be simple.

Comment: You are most likely looking for something like that `$.each(data.listServer`, but still hard to say since we don't know the look of the returned json.

Comment: `Console.log(data);` data in the first function so we can see what your json looks like, also your each should be: `$.each(data, function(key){ loadServer(data[key]); })` assuming your json format. Post json format then we can advise...

Comment: The JSON returned from the first POST just contains a load of objects, each representing a server. I've simplified that code just to represent the problem, that the doSomething() method is only being called once even when 5 servers are returned in the JSON - yet that alert(compName) just above is getting called 5 times - so the JSON returned from the POST within the loadServer function should be irrelevant to the issue?

Comment: Even if you have 5 or 10 objects sent back by your server, they are all stored in a unique "data". That's why the `loadServer` is only called once. If you want to examinate the content of "data", you can use `console.log(JSON.stringify(data));`

Comment: Maybe `$.each(data,function(){loadServer(this.serverName);...` since you are saying alert has been called 5 times, but `data['servername']`  always select the same servername which appears to be the last one.

Comment: And please edit your post, because if you got 5 alerts, that means the second post is occuring 5 times , but 5 times for the same server. And people reading your post assumed this loadServer was called only once and that truly messed with their approach of the problem.

Comment: Have updated post, hopefully the problem is clearer now - apologies!

Comment: Still not working with `loadServer(this.serverName)` ? Cause i am almost sure if you switch to `alert(serverName)` instead you will get 5 times the same serverName. But this.serverName should solve this.

Comment: The loadServer(data['serverName']) portion of the code is working as expected, it is calling the loadServer function 5 times, where the alert(compName) line is also displaying a popup 5 times. It's just that the post within loadServer is only calling the doSomething(resp) once...